# Trigger Apex Trigger if a custom field (bool) is true

Tags: apex, trigger, code

I have this code that sends information to a webhook, I only need to send information when the field WebTrig__c (checkbox) = True. I wrote this code but for both cases it sends the information to the webhook

```
trigger OpportunityWebhookTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    String url = 'https://hook.integromat.com/yidd9alvv698pu6ki5gpzu666nvsjyr';
    String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
        
    for(Opportunity c : [Select WebTrig__c From Opportunity Where Id in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){
        if(c.WebTrig__c = true ){
            Webhook.callout(url, content); 
            Break;  
        }
        else if(c.WebTrig__c = false) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're comparing booleans in an if statement you should use **equality operator** - '==' instead of single '='.

Comment: Though  `if(condition == true)` can be simplified to `if(condition)`, and `if(condition == false)` can be simplified to `if(!condition)`. In general, there's no need to compare two booleans (they can be used directly).